# Need help to solve sonar issue method reference

Tags: java, java-11

I am always getting "Replace this lambda with a method reference" in sonarqube. Below code I have. I am not sure How can I replace to method reference

```
Sting abc = accountMemberList.stream().filter(e -> e.isPrimaryAcc()).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(AccountMember::getSubMemberNo)).findFirst();
```

Also, is this good good practice to "Replace this lambda with a method reference"
I am using java 11.

Comment: It likely wants you to use `filter(AccountMember::isPrimaryAcc)` instead of the lambda.

Comment: Define "good good practice", or even "good practice".  It is up to you (and the other people on your team) to decide whether you prefer lambdas or method references.

Comment: if you are using a proper IDE like intellij, it would show up in the hints what @Slaw has suggested.

Comment: That’s definitely a matter of taste. But you should prefer to be consistent. Since you used a method reference with `.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(AccountMember::getSubMemberNo))`, it makes sense to use `.filter(AccountMember::isPrimaryAcc)` as well.